# configure two button with struct

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am making a simple quiz app with simple questions, I've created struct with name and two answers ( obviously one of them is correct ) but I've no idea how to configure those buttons here's the code any solution will be appericated

```swift
struct EasyQuestions {
    var question: String
    var answers: [Answers]
    var hint: String
    var correctAnswer: String
}
struct Answers {
    var answer1:String
    var answer2:String
}


    var questions:[EasyQuestions] = [
        EasyQuestions(question: "1 + 1", answers: [Answers(answer1: "5", answer2: "2")], hint: "3-1", correctAnswer: "2"),
        EasyQuestions(question: "2 + 2", answers: [Answers(answer1: "1", answer2: "4")], hint: "5-1", correctAnswer: "4")
    ]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configure(with: questions[0])
    }

    func configure(with question: EasyQuestions){
        self.Question.text = question.question
        self.button1.setTitle(question.answers, for: .normal)
        self.button2.setTitle(answer.answer2, for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: Get the title of the tapped button and compare it to the correct answer. You could also use integer for answer :1,2 . And then set button1.tag = 1, button2.tag=2 then check that correctAnswer ==  buttonPressed.tag

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot of code.
You need to read about UIButton class, for example you cannot set title with an array. You need to to have String there.
self.button1.setTitle(question.answers, for: .normal)

You need to add touch responders to react on user's tapping.

You probably want to identify which answer was selected, so you can use tag field of UIButton and assign answer id to it.

You also probably want to show multiple questions so you need to implement a loop presenting an array of buttons.

Here is example of a loop displaying buttons 4 buttons:

```
let buttons: [UIButton] = []
for i in 0..<4 {
buttons.append(UIButton)
buttons[i].frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
buttons[i].tag = i
buttons[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
view?.addSubview(buttons[i])
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
let pickedButtonId: Int = sender.tag
// do something with button
}
```

Comment: its all understandable, but how can i make loop to present array of buttons ?

Comment: I still think you should take a look at some tutorials.